# Get state from a list of cubits

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cubit

I'm trying to create a list that initializes the same cubit per item in the list. Each item in the list has a button that will change its label based on its state. Ex. edit -> submit. What im trying to accomplish is if when I click on any button and there exists any other button which state is not edit make that state edit so that only the button I just pressed is submit. I posted what I have so far. Any help is much appreciated thank you!

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Editable List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 4,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return BlocProvider<Cubit1>(
            create: (context) => Cubit1(),
            child:
                 BlocConsumer<Cubit1, State1>(
                  listener: (context, state) {
                    if(state == State1.editing) {
                        //CHECK IF THERE ARE OTHER TILES
                        //WITH STATES OTHER THAN EDIT 
                        //CHANGE IT BACK TO EDIT IF TRUE
                    }
                  },
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return ListTile(
                                  title: Text('List Tile ${index + 1}'),
                                  trailing: ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      _toggleEditing();
                                    },
                                    child: Text(state == State1.initial ? 'Submit' : 'Edit'),
                                  ),
                                );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```